# How to exclude specific numbers from definition set of pfgplot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I want to plot `y = (3x²-3) / (x+1)(x-4)`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
  \addplot[
    domain=-2:10,
    samples=50
  ]{(3 * x^2 - 3) / ((x + 1) * (x - 4))};
  \addplot[
    mark=square,
  ]coordinates {(-1,1.2)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: plot]

As `4` (as well as `-1`) is not in the definition set (division by zero -> undefined), I want to exclude the point where `x = 4` from the plot, such that the vertical line disappears.
**How can I exclude a point from the definition set of a pfgplot?**

Comment: Since English is not my mother tongue, I'd very appreciate improvements to the question.

Comment: I don't think we need to improve your writing unless you consider that your question is not clearly expressed, in that case you would have to explain it better, no one other than yourself can write an idea in English in your head.

Comment: @Aradnix Do you consider my question to be not clearly expressed?

Comment: Not at all, but I wasn't sure if you thought it was clearly stated in your opening remarks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is to use a number of samples where also a point at 4 is calculated, e.g. 101. When you then add in addition `unbounded coords=jump` then no line will be drawn between the two "sections".

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot[
            domain=-2:10,
            samples=101,                % <-- changed from 50 to 101
            unbounded coords=jump,      % <-- added
        ] {(3 * x^2 - 3) / ((x + 1) * (x - 4))};
        \addplot[
            mark=square,
        ] coordinates {(-1,1.2)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Thank you! But why do I have to change the samples from 50 to 101?

Comment: @Scriptim, I first tried with 51, which should also work. But there seem to be some numerical issues with that and it seems not exactly 4 is used then. 101 works fine.