# pgfplots: How to plot a curve with infinite value as one addplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, coordinates

I want to plot 
`acos(7/x)+acos(-2/x)+acos(5/x)-pi` over `domain=-20:20`.

*I ask myself, whether I can plot this as **one** curve* (not as two curves with different domains).

So I choose `unbounded coords=jump` (like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395898/how-to-exclude-specific-numbers-from-definition-set-of-pfgplot)) 
`\addplot[red, domain=-20:20] {f(x)}; % works not :(` 
but he gives the error `! Missing number, treated as zero.`

I there a possibility?

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
trig format=rad, 
declare function={
a=7;    
b=-2;    
c=5;
f(\x)=acos(a/\x)+acos(b/\x)+acos(c/\x)-pi;
m=max(a,b,c);
},
]
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=middle, 
samples=222,
xmin=-20, 
unbounded coords=jump,
]
\addplot[blue, domain = m:20] {f(x)}; % works :)

%\addplot[red, domain=-20:20] {f(x)}; % works not :(
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`acos` is not defined if the absolute value of its argument is greater than 1. You can define a "regularized" version that yields e.g. `inf` if the argument does not make sense.

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
trig format=rad, 
declare function={
a=7;    
b=-2;    
c=5;
Acos(\x)=(abs(\x)>1?inf:acos(max(-1,min(1,\x))));
f(\x)=Acos(a/\x)+Acos(b/\x)+Acos(c/\x)-pi;
m=max(a,b,c);
},
]
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=middle, 
samples=222,
xmin=-20, 
unbounded coords=jump,
]
%\addplot[blue, domain = m:20] {f(x)}; % works :)

\addplot[red, domain=-20:20] {f(x)}; % works :)
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a parametric plot.  The problem is that `f(-m)` and `f(m)` are NOT infinite, so the line gets interpolated.

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
trig format=rad, 
declare function={
a=7;    
b=-2;    
c=5;
f(\x)=acos(a/\x)+acos(b/\x)+acos(c/\x)-pi;
m=max(a,b,c);
g(\t)=ifthenelse(\t>0,\t+m,\t-m);
}]
\begin{axis}[
variable=t, domain=-20:20, no markers,
axis lines=middle, 
samples=222,% overkill
xmin=-20, 
xmax=20,
unbounded coords=jump
]
\addplot[blue,coordinate] ({g(t)},{f(g(t))});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```